# How to draw a Rectangle in all direction?

Tags: vb.net

i've found this code on the web that allow me to draw a rectangle and keep the Image inside this. But there is a way to make draw this rectangle in all the direction and not only from left to right and top to bottom?
Thank for the help!
Here is the code:

```
Public Class frmSS
Private Declare Auto Function BitBlt Lib "gdi32.dll" ( _
 ByVal hdcDest As IntPtr, _
 ByVal nXDest As Integer, _
 ByVal nYDest As Integer, _
 ByVal nWidth As Integer, _
 ByVal nHeight As Integer, _
 ByVal hdcSrc As IntPtr, _
 ByVal nXSrc As Integer, _
 ByVal nYSrc As Integer, _
 ByVal dwRop As Int32) As Boolean

Private Declare Auto Function GetDC Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr) As IntPtr
Private Declare Auto Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal hDC As IntPtr) As IntPtr

Private Sub frmSS_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
    Me.Location = New Point(0, 0)
    Me.ClientSize = Screen.GetBounds(Me).Size
    Me.BackColor = Color.Gray
    Me.DoubleBuffered = True
    Me.Opacity = 0.4#
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.Cross
    Me.ShowInTaskbar = False
End Sub

Private isDragging As Boolean = False
Private canDrag As Boolean = True
Private pt_start As Point = Point.Empty
Private pt_end As Point = Point.Empty

Private Sub frmSS_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseDown
    If Me.canDrag Then
        Me.isDragging = True
        Me.pt_start = e.Location
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub frmSS_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove
    If Me.isDragging Then
        Me.pt_end = e.Location
        Me.Invalidate()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub frmSS_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseUp
    If Me.isDragging Then
        Me.isDragging = False
        Me.canDrag = False
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
        Dim r As Rectangle = Me.SelectedRectangle
        Me.Hide()
        Application.DoEvents() 'Make sure everything's good and hidden.
        Me.CaptureThisArea(r)
        Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub

Private ReadOnly Property SelectedRectangle() As Rectangle
    Get
        With pt_start
            If .X >= pt_end.X OrElse .Y >= pt_end.Y Then Return Rectangle.Empty
            Return New Rectangle(.X, .Y, pt_end.X - .X, pt_end.Y - .Y)



        End With
    End Get
End Property

Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
    Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics

    Using p As New Pen(Color.Black, 3)
        p.DashStyle = Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dash
        If Me.SelectedRectangle <> Rectangle.Empty Then
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, Me.SelectedRectangle)
            g.DrawRectangle(p, Me.SelectedRectangle)
        End If
    End Using

    MyBase.OnPaint(e)
End Sub

Private Sub CaptureThisArea(ByVal area As Rectangle)
    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(area.Width, area.Height, Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)
    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
        Dim srcDC As IntPtr = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero)
        Dim destDC As IntPtr = g.GetHdc()

        BitBlt(destDC, 0, 0, area.Width, area.Height, srcDC, area.X, area.Y, 13369376) 'SRCCOPY = 13369376

        g.ReleaseHdc(destDC)
        ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, srcDC)
    End Using
    Dim s_dl As New SaveFileDialog()
    s_dl.Filter = "Bitmap Images (*.bmp)|*.bmp"
    If s_dl.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.Cancel Then Exit Sub
    bmp.Save(s_dl.FileName)
    MessageBox.Show("File saved!!!")
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.  What other direction is there between up, down, left, and right?

Comment: Are you trying to rotate the rectangle?

Comment: i wanna drwa the rectangle moving the mouse in all the directions, if you try this code you can see that once you're selecting the rectangle you can mouve the mouse only down and right.

Answer (score 1):

You need to try to determine the rectangle based on the initial MouseDown point and during the MouseMove, see if the current mouse coordinates need to be adjusted based on minimums and maximums of each X and Y value:

Comment out pt_end and add a dragRect variable:

```
'\\ Private pt_end As Point = Point.Empty
Private dragRect As Rectangle = Rectangle.Empty
```

Change your MouseMove event to this:

```
Private Sub frmSS_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove
  If Me.isDragging Then
    Dim minPoint As New Point(Math.Min(e.Location.X, pt_start.X), _
                              Math.Min(e.Location.Y, pt_start.Y))
    Dim maxPoint As New Point(Math.Max(e.Location.X, pt_start.X), _
                              Math.Max(e.Location.Y, pt_start.Y))
    dragRect = New Rectangle(minPoint, New Size(maxPoint.X - minPoint.X, _
                                                maxPoint.Y - minPoint.Y))
    Me.Invalidate()
  End If
End Sub
```

From there, change your code to use dragRect instead of `SelectedRectangle`, which I commented out.

Comment: Thank you, i've changed the MouseMove event but i don't understand how to use dragRect instead of Selected Rectangle.. could you please tell me how to do that? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Pablo Delete the `SelectedRectangle` function, and then replace all of the reference errors where you were using `SelectedRectangle` with `dragRect`.  Like in `MouseUp`: `Me.CaptureThisArea(dragRect)` and in `OnPaint`, replace `SelectedRectangle` with `dragRect`.